# How can I make my files hard to navigate to prevent Inspect Element data scraping?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know Inspect Element can't be disabled, however I think making my files hard to navigate would help. Is there anyway I can achieve this? Does anyone have any ideas, such as changing directories or copying files and changing them every so often.

Also, how can I hide url extensions? Thanks.

Comment: you can use [obfuscation](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/obfuscation-what-is-obfuscation-in-javascript-why-obfuscation-is-used-f6a5f5bcf022) technique and also minification for your code can help.

Comment: have you tried `pretty URLs` and authenticated resource access?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser just have data that I dont want to be scraped.

Comment: Then don't put it on a website.

Comment: Once the browser downloaded the resource from server. You can't prevent it from scraping

Comment: Its not personal or anything, if someone gets to it then sure, I just dont want lots of people doing so.

Comment: To be able to display data to a user, the web browser first downloads it. By putting it on a webpage, you're writing instructions for how to download the data. I think either you don't understand how that works, or you're trying to do something slightly different, but haven't explained it well.

Comment: I'm pretty new to websites. I'm used to making apps. I know this, but I would prefer to add a few obstacles into the file system.

Comment: What you're asking is impossible to do unfortunately, so don't waste your time worrying about it :)